# Check if class contains class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

On a website are some posts in the class "content".

If the class "content" contains a other class with the name "rcm" and a blockquote, the blockquote needs a css rule.

**Example**

**Post 1:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="rcm"></div>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
```

**Post 2:**

```
<div class="content">
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
```

**Post 3:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="rcm"></div>
</div>
```

**Target:**

Only the blockquote in the post **Nr. 1** need the following css rule, because only in Nr. 1 the class "content" has the class "rcm" and a "blockquote":

```
$("blockquote").css({"display": "inherit", "width": "auto"});
```

**I tried:**

```
if (($(".content").hasClass("rcm")) && ($(".content").hasClass("blockquote"))) {
  $("blockquote").css({"display": "inherit", "width": "auto"});
}
```

But that did not work, because I think I need something with "each", because there are more classes with the name content?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation: just use css sibling selectors for this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators

```
<style>
.content > .rcm ~ blockquote {
    display: inherit;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
```

achieves what you need

Answer (score 1):

`$('.content .rcm blockquote').css({"display": "inherit", "width": "auto"});`

I assume content will be always parent class and child has rcm it rcm will be same use selector `$('.content.rcm blockquote')`. No need to add check if has class

Comment: that does not work, because blockquote is not in .rcm

Comment: $('.content .rcm').closest('.content').find('blockquote').css({"display": "inherit", "width": "auto"}); Try this

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working now :).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var contents = $('.content');
contents.each(function(){
    var item = $(this)
      // another condition
    if(item.find(".rcm")[0] && item.find(".blockquote")[0]){
       console.log('OK')
       item.css({"display": "inherit", "width": "auto"});
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
    <div class="rcm"></div>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="rc3m"></div>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for getting into. This does not work, maybe because blockquote is no class? So hasClass does not work? and item.css is for the blockquote?

Comment: Thank you for the edits. It looks correct but did not work. Maybe it has todo with item.css? is item.css for the blockquote?

Comment: AND Uncaught TypeError: item.hasClass is not a function

Comment: Thank you. Its working almost. Now the class content gets the css but the blockquote needs the css and ONLY the blockquote the blockquote where its true. Could you check this?

Comment: @DareDevil 's answer is perfect

Comment: @lwohlhart 's answer will be more effect, normal method, we don't need javascript/jquery

Comment: I dont think so, because the blockquote is not in the class .rcm.

Comment: your code is working but the class content gets the css rule. Could you please change it, that the blockquote will get the css?

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and time. Its also working. I use the CSS method.